# Able to see values but not graph in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, parsefloat

I have values which I am trying to implement in High charts. Please see the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xbk57jdo/1/)

If you see the fiddle you will find this code

```
 MARKETS[0].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname0, month)) || "null");
 MARKETS[1].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname1, month)) || "null");
 MARKETS[2].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname2, month)) || "null");
 MARKETS[3].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname3, month)) || "null");
 MARKETS[4].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname4, month)) || "null");
 MARKETS[5].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname5, month)) || "null");
 MARKETS[6].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname6, month)) || "null");
 MARKETS[7].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname7, month)) || "null");
```

Where I am trying to replace the some values with null. When I put null I am getting a graph that displays values but no colors as the fiddle link shown above. If I replace null with value `0.0` I am getting the graph. But I don't want to replace 0.0 I want to replace with `null`. This is the [ORIGINAL HIGHCHART](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-missing/) Where I took reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null` is not a string. use `null` instead of `"null"`, for example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbk57jdo/3/)):

```
MARKETS[0].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname0, month)) || null);
// ...
```

You can read more about [strings](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) and [null/undefined](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_typeof.asp) on w3schools.

Comment: Thanq Once again Ondkloss. And can you also please tell how can I put the series in loop instead of giving  this everytime series: [{
            name: mname0,
            data: MARKETS[0]
        }, {
            name: mname1,
            data: MARKETS[1]
        }]

Comment: A bit off-topic, but see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbk57jdo/4/). Just prepare an array of the objects and use it in the options.